# How to remove popup from Pairing in Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm writing an app on 2 devices, that pairs the 2 devices and sends a general message.

Whenever I start the pairing to the other device (even inside my own app on my other device) I get a prompt saying "do you want to pair device xxx"

(similar to this popup >)

[image]

and the user actually has to press on pair. so that the 2 devices would be paired.

assuming I'm having my own app on both phones, 
is there a way for me to pair them automatically without the other user would actually have to press on "Pair"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pairing without user interaction requires the *BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED* permission, which is not available to third-party developers / apps.

Quoting the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED):

> Allows applications to pair bluetooth devices without user interaction, and to allow or disallow phonebook access or message access. This is not available to third party applications.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"